# Import non-react class fails

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I'm using react in a project and importing of React.Component classes works without issue. However when trying to import vanilla es6 classes that do not extend anything its failing. Even though eslint compiles without issue. The imported class is also null in the constructor.

```
import Utils from "../../common/services/Utils";
componentWilReceiveProps(newProps){
    Utils // here is null
}

class Utils {
    test() {
        // do nothing
    }
}

export default Utils;
```

Comment: Why are you importing something with the same name as your class's exports?

Comment: @Aurora0001 classes are not hoisted. But i suppose he made a mistake, it's  separated. David can you show the export code?

Comment: @TheReason maybe so, but it's still a recipe for disaster in my opinion. Much better to have unambiguous names for things (using the [`as`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) syntax if necessary).

Comment: @Aurora0001 agree. it would be better to if David formats it in a corresponding way.